# where to put relation models in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm

First the simplified scenario:

```
from django.db import models

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    description = models.TextField()

class Merchant(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()

class MerchantProductMapping(models.Model):
    merchant = models.ForeignKey(Merchant)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    inventory_limit = models.IntegerField()
```

I have another model for the relation (`MerchantProductMapping`) because the relation has attributes of its own. Now the requirements of the `Merchant` and the `Product` model have grown to a point where they demand separate apps of their own. The `merchant` app's `models.py` is where the `Merchant` model will live and the `product` app's `models.py` is where the `Product` model will live.
What I need help with is the relation model `MerchantProductMapping`. It is needed by both apps, where should I put it ? I've been reading up on mixins and wondering if they could help me somehow.
EDIT: I should add that the app was rendered server side earlier. Now it will be done using angular client - REST api approach. And django rest framework will be used on top of django.

Comment: You can put in any `models.py` file. In database, it will be just new table in database.

Comment: I know I can put it anywhere. What I want to know is where it 'should' be put.

Comment: My vote goes to `merchant`'s `model.py`.

Comment: then import it in `category`'s `models.py` when required ?

Answer (score 3):

Create "common" app for such purposes ... you can put there decorators, templatetags, base forms, base models, login|logout redirect views and urls, ajax views, base filters, base tables ... etc

Note: create "apps" python package dir (dir with `__init__.py` inside it) and (refactor) move all your apps there.

EDIT:

Another way - create "models" python package dir and split your models.py to logically separated files inside package

Comment: can you explain what you mean by 'base' ? How can I use your strategy in my scenario ? What I had earlier was a single models.py, but it has grown too large. Won't a common app defeat the purpose of modularizing my project into apps.

Comment: I've added another way

Comment: but my apps pretty much revolve around a central model. So I'm not sure about aggregating them under a single directory. I'm thinking that if I add it to either of the apps as Lafada is suggesting, or under a single package as you are in your alternate solution, It will not be as modular or reusable. I don't want to have to import everything everywhere. Your previous solution is closer to the mark. I'll leave the merchant and the product app be. The app requiring the relation will have the relation. This app will not cover the merchant's relations with other models, but worry about itself only